About weakly metrizable and bounded subset of a Banach space
Let $X$ be a Banach space and $w$ its weak topology. In a doctoral thesis, I have read a result, which (if I understood correctly) sound like this: "If $B$ is a  bounded and $w$-metrizable subset of X then there is a countable subset, set $D$, of the unit sphere of $X^{*}$, $S^*$, such that for each $g\in S^{*}$ and $\varepsilon>0$ there is $f\in D$ such that $\sup\{|g(x)-f(x)|: x\in B\}<\varepsilon$. It is this assert true? I know that such a set $B$ is first countable (maybe we can not get much more information from its $w$-metrizability), by I do not know to prove the assert.
Many thanks in advance for your comments.


I doubt that this is true for arbitrary sets $C$, maybe you just need it for absolutely convex sets. Then the theorem of bipolars could help to prove the lemma. I do not see how (and why) you want $D$ to be contained in the sphere $S$.

Thanks for your comment. And, if we assume, in addition, that C is weakly compact?

Even for weakly compact and absolutely convex sets, I don't see how to prove this lemma. Where it is from and how is it used?

The result is used in the image attached in the post, from a doctoral thesis

Which thesis? And how is lemma 4.3 used?

Thanks @Jochen. The thesis is "Separability and Metrisability  in Locally Convex Spaces", by Neill Robertson. It is available in https://open.uct.ac.za/items/78d0cf8b-edfd-40cb-8211-34bc0a7a6347

Thanks. Unfortunately, I still don't get a clue. I think that the following is true: If $C$ is a bounded weakly metrizable subset of a normed space $F$ then there is a countable set $D\subseteq F'$ such that, for every $g\in F'$ and $\varepsilon >0$, there is $f\in D$ with $\sup{|g(x)-f(x)|:x\in C}\le\varepsilon$.
By a result of Kalton (mentioned at the beginning of Robertson's thesis) one can assume $C$ absolutely convex and then the result follows from the bipolar theorem (AFAIR, something similar to this lemma is somewhere in Grothendieck's lectures Topological Vector Spaces).

What I do not see is that one can additionally have $f$ in the unit sphere $S$ of $F'$ if $g\in S$. It seems that the author of the thesis is still in academia https://science.uct.ac.za/department-mathematics/dr-neill-robertson
You could send him an e-mail and ask for an explanation.

Again, many thanks for your comments. In the thesis is asserted that " if A is a bounded and w-metrizable, then Aºº as subset of X** is w(X**,X*)-metrizable. But, as you, i do not seem how the claimed separability of the thesis (i.e., the question of this post) can be derived. Maybe I should send an e-mail to the autor.

I have posed the problem on MathOverflow https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480109. Maybe, some Banach space experts now the answer (my guess is that the characterization apparently used is not true in general).

The question has now been answered (positively) https://mathoverflow.net/questions/480109/weakly-metrizable-sets-in-normed-spaces/480422#480422
